# Как вставить данные из переменных в таблицу?

Tags: python, mysql, база-данных, pymysql, передача-параметров

Нужно вставить данные из переменных в таблицу.

```
# insert data
enter_name = input()
enter_password = input()
enter_email = input()
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("insert into users (name, password, email) VALUES (enter_name, enter_password, enter_email)")
    connection.commit()
    print("Insert Table successfully")
```

Но так сделать нельзя, выводиться ошибка :

> 1054, "Unknown column 'enter_name' in 'field list'"

Я пробовал сделать так:

```
cursor.execute("insert into `users` (name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    (enter_name, enter_password, enter_email))
```

Но снова выводилась ошибка:

> Error
> not all arguments converted during string formatting

Comment: Немного не правильно оформил

Comment: Error
not all arguments converted during string formatting

Использую pymysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению в Python не существует **единого** стандарта для [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) и `placeholders` отличаются для разных БД. Для PyMySQL нужно использовать `%s` вместо `?`.

```
cursor.execute("insert into users (name, password, email) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
               (enter_name, enter_password, enter_email))
```